# Не выполняется условие if, хотя else выполняется

Tags: java

```
public class Library {
    String address;
    ArrayList<Book> books = new ArrayList<Book>();

    void addBook(Book book){
       books.add(book);
    }

    static void printOpeningHours() {
        System.out.print("9AM - 9PM");
    }

    void printAddress(){
        System.out.println(address);
    }

    void borrowBook(String name){
        for (Book object:books) {
            if(object.getTitle().equals(name)){
                System.out.println("Here is you book - " + name);
                books.remove(object);
            }
            else {
                System.out.println("We don`t have this book in our library.");
                 }
        }
    }

    void printAvailableBooks(){
        for (Book object:books) {
            System.out.println(object.getTitle());
        }
    }

    void returnBook(String name){
        books.add(new Book(name));
    }

    public Library(String address) {
        this.address = address;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Create two libraries
        Library firstLibrary = new Library("10 Main St.");
        Library secondLibrary = new Library("228 Liberty St.");


        // Add four books to the first library
        firstLibrary.addBook(new Book("The Da Vinci Code"));
        firstLibrary.addBook(new Book("Le Petit Prince"));
        firstLibrary.addBook(new Book("A Tale of Two Cities"));
        firstLibrary.addBook(new Book("The Lord of the Rings"));

        // Print opening hours and the addresses
        System.out.println("Library hours:");
        printOpeningHours();
        System.out.println();

        System.out.println("Library addresses:");
        firstLibrary.printAddress();
        secondLibrary.printAddress();
        System.out.println();

        // Try to borrow The Lords of the Rings from both libraries
        System.out.println("Borrowing The Lord of the Rings:");
        firstLibrary.borrowBook("The Lord of the Rings");
        firstLibrary.borrowBook("The Lord of the Rings");
        secondLibrary.borrowBook("The Lord of the Rings");
        System.out.println();

        // Print the titles of all available books from both libraries
        System.out.println("Books available in the first library:");
        firstLibrary.printAvailableBooks();
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println("Books available in the second library:");
        secondLibrary.printAvailableBooks();
        System.out.println();

        // Return The Lords of the Rings to the first library
        System.out.println("Returning The Lord of the Rings:");
        firstLibrary.returnBook("The Lord of the Rings");
        System.out.println();

        // Print the titles of available from the first library
        System.out.println("Books available in the first library:");
        firstLibrary.printAvailableBooks();
    }
}
```

Почему-то не выводит сообщение о том, что книга взята и не удаляет её из списка доступных книг, хотя условие else выполняется и выводит, что книги нет в списке.

> Borrowing The Lord of the Rings:
>
> We don't have this book in our library.
>
> We don't have this book in our library.

```
public class Book {

String title;
boolean borrowed;

// Creates a new Book
public Book(String bookTitle) {
    this.title = bookTitle;
}

// Marks the book as rented
public void rented() {
    this.borrowed = true;
}

// Marks the book as not rented
public void returned() {
    this.borrowed = false;
}

// Returns true if the book is rented, false otherwise
public boolean isBorrowed() {
    // Implement this method
    if(borrowed == true){
        return true;
    }
    else{
        return false;
    }
}

// Returns the title of the book
public String getTitle() {
    return this.title;
}

public static void main(String[] arguments) {
    // Small test of the Book class
    Book example = new Book("The Da Vinci Code");
    System.out.println("Title (should be The Da Vinci Code): " + example.getTitle());
    System.out.println("Borrowed? (should be false): " + example.isBorrowed());
    example.rented();
    System.out.println("Borrowed? (should be true): " + example.isBorrowed());
    example.returned();
    System.out.println("Borrowed? (should be false): " + example.isBorrowed());
}
}
```

Мое решение проблемы:

```
void borrowBook(String name){
    Iterator<Book> it = books.iterator();
    int x = 0;
    while(x < 1){
        while (it.hasNext()) {
            Book book = it.next();
            if (book.getTitle().equals(name)) {
                x++;
                it.remove();
            }
        }
    break;
    }
    if(x==1){
        System.out.println("Here is your book - " + name);
    }
    else{
        System.out.println("We don't have this book in our library");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Чтобы удалять элементы из коллекции во время перебора нужно использовать итераторы.
Попробуйте так

```
int borrowBook(String name){
    Iterator<Book> it = books.iterator();
    while (it.hasNext()) {
       Book book = it.next();
       if (book.getTitle().equals(name)) {
           System.out.println("Here is you book - " + name);
           it.remove();
           return 1;
       }
   }
   System.out.println("We don`t have this book in our library.");
   return 0;

}
```

Comment: Ну или так: ArrayList<Book> temp = new ArrayList<Book>(books)             
 for (Book object : temp)

Comment: Используя итераторы, книга удалилась из списка и вывело сообщение, но теперь на каждую проверку книги, программа выводит, что книги нет. 
    Borrowing The Lord of the Rings: 
    We don't have this book in our library.
    We don't have this book in our library. 
    We don't have this book in our library.
    Here is you book - The Lord of the Rings
    We don't have this book in our library.
    We don't have this book in our library.
    We don't have this book in our library.

Comment: исправил как по моему должно быть

Comment: Выводит некорректно, но я разобрался, почему он не удалял её из списка, дальше думаю, что сам смогу исправить, чтобы отображалось корректно. Спасибо большое!